# Selected Value from single column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with data populated from an XML binding.

I want to know how I can obtain the selected row in C#, more specifically I want to return the value of the 'ID' from the selected row from my dataset.

I can get the entire row contents with:

```
 var downloadlistselected = downloadList.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

However, I only want the contents from the first column.

Can anyone help?

### XAML

```
  <Grid.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider Source="E:\downloader\downloadConfig.xml" XPath="/xservdownload/downloadItem"></XmlDataProvider>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <DataGrid x:Name="downloadList" Height="191" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="DownloadListSelectionChanged" DataContext="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding XPath=ID}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=Name}" Width="350"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding XPath=Status}" Width="100"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines should do:

```
var item = (XmlNode)downloadList.SelectedItem;
var value = item.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
```

Key being that the selected item should be an `XmlNode` from which you can get whatever you need.

Comment: Still a little stuck. 'item' is populated with the entire XmlElement and 'value' is null. As the data is already present in the DataGrid, can it be obtained this way at all?

Comment: @Damo: The item should be the entire element, you then just need to get the child element `ID`, if `Value` doesn't do it for nodes use `InnerText`.

Comment: @Damo: Yes, use `InnerText`, [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx) is - as can be seen in the reference - pointless for elements. As i said, something *"along those lines"*...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function, hope it helps.

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, int row, int column)
        {
            DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dataGrid, row);
            if (rowContainer != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

                // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                    dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);

                    cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
                }

                return cell;
            }

            return null;
}
```

After you get the DataGridCell, you might also need to get child visual by VisualTreeHelper class.